# Animating a div in jquery using math.random();

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, random

Im currently working on a project that has to update the height of a div (green color) inside a circle by manual data input.

Here is a jsfiddle of the circle im talking about: http://jsfiddle.net/bphs5k8v/

What i need to have happen is the green color to move to random heights within the circle every few seconds (for testing purposes). But i honestly have no clue on how i can accomplish this.
I was able to succesfully do this with CSS animations but figured i would need to use javascript for the result of the project anyway.

```
//HTML
<div class="circle">
        <div id="animateddiv1">
    </div>  
</div>

//CSS
.circle {border-radius: 50%; position: relative; overflow: hidden; background: #8a8a8a; width: 165px; height: 165px; display: inline-block; margin: 0 75px; box-shadow: 0px 4px 2px #191919;}
#animateddiv1 {background: #63B23A; position: absolute; top: 130px; width: 200px; height: 165px;}
```

I seek your help! 
thanks :D

Comment: Try **[jQuery animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)**. heres an example for you [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bphs5k8v/2/).

Comment: Using theses CSS property, you have to change the `#animateddiv1` ` `top` CSS property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to read jQuery docs http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Here example with smooth animation:
http://jsfiddle.net/bphs5k8v/8/

```
$(function () {
    var animated = $('#animateddiv1');

    function animate() {
        animated.animate({
            height: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + '%'
        }, 350);
    }

    setInterval(animate, 350);
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use keyframes in CSS, as you stated in your question, but its hard to sort of randomise those numbers and you are limited to how many different keyframes you put in.

A simple JS version would be to run a `setInterval` function which randomly generates a number between 0 and 165px and then push this into the css changing the `top` position.

Something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    var rand = Math.floor((Math.random() * 165));
    $('#animateddiv1').css('top', rand);
  }, 2000);
});
```

```css
.circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #8a8a8a;
  width: 165px;
  height: 165px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 75px;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 2px #191919;
}
#animateddiv1 {
  background: #63B23A;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 165px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="circle">
  <div id="animateddiv1">
  </div>
</div>
```

You can then improve this code to your liking, maybe making it animate through the numbers etc.

Comment: Awesome thank you very much! I was also looking for a smooth transition but some other user already suggested that :-)

Answer (score 2):

Position the inner Div to bottom & Change the value of height on Timeout via Jquery

JQuery

```
window.setInterval(function(){
value = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
    $("#animateddiv1").css('height',value)
}, 1000);
```

CSS

```
.circle {border-radius: 50%; position: relative; overflow: hidden; background: #8a8a8a; width: 165px; height: 165px; display: inline-block; margin: 0 75px; box-shadow: 0px 4px 2px #191919;}

#animateddiv1 {background: #63B23A; position: absolute; bottom:0; width: 200px; height: 165px;}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3lackRos3/bphs5k8v/7/)

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:use `setInterval` to get what you desired.

```js
setInterval(function(){
    $('#animateddiv1').animate({top:Math.floor(Math.random() *180 +5)})
},1000);
```

```css
.circle {border-radius: 50%; position: relative; overflow: hidden; background: #8a8a8a; width: 165px; height: 165px; display: inline-block; margin: 0 75px; box-shadow: 0px 4px 2px #191919;}
#animateddiv1 {background: #63B23A; position: absolute; top: 130px; width: 200px; height: 165px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="circle">
        <div id="animateddiv1">
    </div>  
</div>
```